# MSAL Python ConfidentialClientApplication.acquire_token_for_client(scope) returning token with no role/scope

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here? Here's how I'm calling it:

```
  auth_app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    os.environ["MS_CLIENT_ID"],
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    client_credential=os.environ["MS_SECRET"]
  )
  result = auth_app.acquire_token_for_client(SCOPES)
```

It works when I use the tenant id of an organization I own, but not a third party organization.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out; I was authorizing my app with a user that did not have admin level permissions, which only authorized the delegated permissions. Once I authorized it with an administrator app it worked.